# Oracle constraint ON DELETE SET NULL cannot validate

Tags: oracle11g

Oracle 11.2.0.2 - import data pumped a schema from a 10.2.0.3 instance in which several constraints were set as ON DELETE SET NULL, so that some orphaned rows exist (by design).  During the data import I received errors about parent keys not being found, so I recreated the constraints in the new environment using novalidate (as I want the existing orphans to stay orphans but new rows need to be initially created referencing a valid parent row).

However, now I can't figure out how to make these indexes 'valid' as oracle complains about parent keys not being found when I try to enable.

How do I set these constraints to valid while maintaining existing orphans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A referential constraint cannot be set "valid" if the parent keys don't exist. If you're using ON DELETE SET NULL, I'd expect the child tables to have NULL for the parent keys anyway. In your case I'd look for rows which *don't* have NULL - these are the ones which are tripping up the constraint.

Comment: sorry, I don't completely understand - shouldn't I expect a mix of children rows with matching parents and others with NULLs?  Will the constraint still work if its not in a valid state?

Comment: When you try to set a constraint as "validated", Oracle will validate it. If there are any children rows with no matching parents, it will raise an exception. If you don't want the constraint validated for existing rows, use `ENABLE NOVALIDATE`. http://psoug.org/definition/VALIDATE.htm